# Show date picker with month and year only for lollipop 5.0 in android

Tags: android, date, picker

Show date picker with month and year only for lollipop 5.0 in android, it can be done in lower versions but how can i do it for android 5.0.

Comment: Can you add more details please?

Comment: have you tried any code? What problem you are facing? Please clarify it.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by setting your DatePicker to spinner mode and getting
the Spinner for Day and hiding it programmatically.

Here is the XML (dialog_date_picker.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_time_set"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Set"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code to do it.

```
private Calendar mCalendar;
...

mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

final View dialogView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dialog_date_picker, null);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

datePicker.init(mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),null);


LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)datePicker.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout ll2 = (LinearLayout)ll.getChildAt(0);
ll2.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_time_set).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view)
  {    
    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

    mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(),
    datePicker.getMonth(),
    datePicker.getDayOfMonth());

    alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: This hides the month and keeps day of the month. I guess the order in which they are presented is dependent on your locale. Blindly relying on a fixed order of UI elements isn't an approach I would recommend. It would be more reliable (though not fully still) if you combined it with @BogdanAksonenko's `Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")` and scan `ll2`'s children for a child with a matching id.

Comment: Or, well, I said scan children - no need to do that manually obviously, all it takes is using `findViewById`

Comment: Don't forget to call `alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.date_of_birth);`, `alertDialog.setView(dialogView)` and `alertDialog.show();`

Comment: Unfortunately the android:datePickerMode xml attribute only works in 21+

Answer (score 4):

This should work for all android versions (api > 11)

```
datePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I get NPE on Lolipop. View isn't found

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference. This is error log.

Answer (score -3):

i wrote a simple, hope it help you

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.show();
```

Comment: Okay, thanks!! but i want only month and year also not date even.

Comment: r u read the question???  read again and update your answer/delete it  Qtn - **Show date picker with month and year only for lollipop 5.0 in android**